# Specify a .env file in Django in command line or vscode launch.json

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

At the moment I have a Django project running in VS Code.  This currently uses a single `.env` file to connect to a SQL Server database.

**environments/.env**

```ini
DATABASE_URL=mssql://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@SERVER_NAME/DATABASE_NAME
```

**settings.py**

```py
import environ


env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
ENVIRONMENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "environments")

environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(ENVIRONMENT_DIR, '.env'))
env = environ.Env()

...

DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db_url(),
    }
}
```

__.vscode/launch.json

This is ran in VS Code with the following launch configuration:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "django": true
        },
    ]
}
```

### Question

The question is, is it possible to have a multitude of different environments to connect to using different multiple environment files?  Something like:

- dev.env
- test.env
- prod.env

Then get VS Code to run a specific .env from the `launch.json`.

Sources:

https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/
https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#multiple-env-files
https://djangostars.com/blog/configuring-django-settings-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can specify environment variables as per this issue - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6986.

Therefore changes required are:

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "env": {
                "ENVIRONMENT_FILE": "dev.env"
            },
            "django": true
        },
    ]
}
```

**settings.py**

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
ENVIRONMENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "environments")
ENVIRONMENT_FILE = os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT_FILE", default=".env")
ENVIRONMENT_FILE_FULL_PATH = os.path.join(ENVIRONMENT_DIR, ENVIRONMENT_FILE)

environ.Env.read_env(ENVIRONMENT_FILE_FULL_PATH)
env = environ.Env()
```