# Django set environment variable via command line and use in Migrations

Tags: python, django, command-line-arguments, django-migrations

Following on from this question - [Specify a .env file in Django in command line or vscode launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036952/specify-a-env-file-in-django-in-command-line-or-vscode-launch-json).  So we have an environment file for dev, test, and production - which is specified in an environment variable `ENVIRONMENT_FILE`.

The .env file holds the database connection information (connection strings).

However, I'm struggling to pass this information when running the migration command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I need to be able to specify which environment I want the migrations to run on.

Is it possible to setup environment variables before migrations can be run?

Answer (score 1):

You can load in the environment variables in your `settings.py` file.

If you have separate `.env` files for separate environments, and it is managed by the `ENVIRONMENT_FILE` variable, you can use something like [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to read your env files,

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(os.getenv("ENVIRONMENT_FILE", ".env"))
```

Then, if your env file looks like this

```
DATABASE_URL=some-url-over-here
```

you can access these anywhere in your django application using `os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')`

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables before you run the migration command.  In PowerShell you can do something like:

```
$env:ENVIRONMENT_FILE='test.env'
python manage.py migrate
```